# In TFS, is there a way to create a query to only show tests at a certain outcome?

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to create a test suite query that would only pull back as a result a test case that is not at a state of "passed".

The set up I have is across various Static suits in a tree structure similar to below:

- Functional Tests

  - Feature 1

    - Page 1 Tests (40)
    - Page 2 Tests (27)
    - etc...
  - Feature 2

    - Page 1 Tests (22)
    - Page 2 Tests (18)
    - etc...
- Automated Tests

  - Area 1

    - Function 1 (73)
    - Function 2 (54)
    - etc...

I have created charts at the top level (Functional Tests and Automated tests) that record the results of the tests after they have been run, including those that haven't been run, but what i want is to be able to see an overall list or tests that haven't had a "pass" result against them.

Is this possible? Unfortunately we don't have the MTM desktop application so all I can use is the TFS webview and query builders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not able to use work item query to filter the  test result pass or not.

To see the overall status of test cases in a test plan/test suite, and to identify which test cases are passing/ failing at a test plan/test suite level, you would need to create an **Excel report**. Base on [data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manage-reports-data-warehouse-cube), you could import the date to excel and use multiple tools in excel to filter the result.

See this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shankars/2011/03/04/using-excel-reports-with-microsoft-test-manager-to-identify-test-state-at-a-test-plan-level/) post for more details on how to use excel report.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had a feeling this might be the case